# jquery tree view cache

Tags: jquery, treeview

How do I apply caching when using jquery treeview plugin. 
I need to show selected tree open when refreshed as well.

http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

**Code**

```
<div class="Content">
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.treeview" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.treeview" %>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery("#page_tree").treeview({
            persist: "location",
            collapsed: true
        });
    });
</script>

<ul id="page_tree">
<% @pages.each do |page| %>

  <li id ="title">
    <%= page.name %>
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "#{page.title}" %></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the `persist` option. You can view the documentation on what options are available here http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Treeview/treeview#options

*Example*

```
$(".selector").treeview({
    persist: "cookie",
   cookieId: "navigationtree"
})
```

*Update*

The example code that they use for cookie based persistence which works on the demo page - [sample 3](http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/) (the location based is sample 2 and it doesn't seem to work) is as follows:

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#page_tree').treeview({
            collapsed: true,
            persist: cookie
        })    
    })
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="page_tree">
<% @pages.each do |page| %>
    <li id="title"><span> <%= page.name %> </span>
    <ul>
        <li> <%= link_to "#{page.title}" %> </li>
    </ul>    
    </li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

My only other advice would be, if this does not work, try statically linking to the javascript/css files and see if that works, also you will want to use the `cookie.js` script.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/jquery.treeview.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

Comment: hi jon, not working when used your options . i am using only two options right now persist: "location",
            collapsed: true. I need to show selected tree open when refresh also . thanks

Comment: If you are setting the `persist:` to location, it looks for the anchor that matches the location.href and activates that part of the treeview. With cookie it will write the location to a cookie on each click and restore the data on reload. You may not have it setup correctly to use location. Can you try cookie instead?

Comment: yeah if i changed to "cookie", the "+" buttons are not showing and unable to view sub links under parent .

Comment: Can you post your html and javascript? I could help more if I could look at some of the code. Thanks

Comment: Just FYI you can edit your original question to include more code. You should only post an answer if you have figured out the issue and are answering your own question. I will be editing my answer here in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="Content">
  <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.treeview" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.treeview" %>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery("#page_tree").treeview({
        persist: "location",
        collapsed: true
      });
    });
  </script>

  <ul id="page_tree">
    <% @pages.each do |page| %>

      <li id ="title">
        <%= page.name %>
        <ul>
            <li><%= link_to "#{page.title}" %></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question about an outdated jQuery plugin, but I just encountered this problem today.

If you want to use `persist: 'cookie'` you NEED to include jquery.cookie.js. Otherwise the +/- icons will disappear and nothing will work.

This is old code, so I grabbed jquery.cookie.js from the treeview's git repo for compatibility:
https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-treeview/tree/master/demo

Also, `collapsed: true` seems counter to the idea of persistence.

Include:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/treeview/jquery.treeview.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/treeview/jquery.treeview.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/treeview/lib/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#page_tree").treeview({
        persist: "cookie"
    });
});
```